# Is this an appropriate use of abstract classes and inheritance?

Tags: python, object-oriented

This is a simple app that starts the webcam either in color or in grayscale mode depending on what the user wants:

[image]

The grayscale camera is implemented via the `GrayVideo` class and the color camera through `ColorVideo`. I wanted to have a common `show_current_frame` for both the `ColorVideo` and `GrayVideo` objects. That `show_current_frame` gets the current frame from the process method and displays it in the GUI. Since the color and the grayscale videos need different frame processing, I needed to have different `process` methods for `ColorVideo` and `GrayVideo`. So, I thought of having a `Video` class with an abstract `process` method.

Is this a decent use of abstract classes and inheritance?
What other problems and possible improvements do you see in my code?
Or is the design wrong in the first place?

```
import cv2
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Video(ABC):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(source) # If source = 0 the webcam starts

    def get_raw_frame(self):
        # Get a bolean and current frame (numpy array) from the webcam
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if ret:
            return frame

    @abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        # Method to process frames.
        # Method will be overwritten by subclasses
        pass

    def show_current_frame(self):
        # Get processed frame and show it in the GUI
        current_frame = self.process()
        cv2.imshow('Live', current_frame)

    def end(self):
        # Releases webcam and closes GUI window
        self.capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()


class ColorVideo(Video):

    def process(self):
        # Since raw frames are in color, there's no processing needed
        return self.get_raw_frame()


class GrayVideo(ColorVideo):

    def process(self):
        # Grayscaling the raw frames
        raw_frame = self.get_raw_frame()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(raw_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        return gray


user_preference = input('Enter "c" for color, or "g" for grayscale: ')

if user_preference == 'c':
    video = ColorVideo(source=0)
if user_preference == 'g':
    video = GrayVideo(source=0)


while True:
    video.show_current_frame()

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        video.end()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a decent use of abstract classes and inheritance?

Yes, it's decent. My personal preference is, rather than using `ABC`, simply

```
def process(self):
    # Method to process frames.
    # Method will be overwritten by subclasses
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

You can also simplify this somewhat by

- Renaming `Video` to `ColorVideo`
- Deleting the class that is now called `ColorVideo`
- Rather than making `process` abstract, make it "virtual" (in C++ parlance): make it take the contents of what is now `get_raw_frame` and delete `get_raw_frame`
- In the child `GrayVideo`, override `process` to call its `super().process` and convert the results

If you're concerned that this more minimal representation is confusing (i.e. why is a `GrayVideo` a `ColorVideo`?) then you can keep `Video` as a conceptually abstract class, and simply

```
class ColorVideo(Video):
    pass
```

Other stuff:

- `end` should actually be the `__exit__` of a context manager;
- it looks like your `source` argument should take a default of `0`;
- make a `main` function called by standard `__name__` guard.

Comment: Cool, thank you! That made it a lot more compact! I never thought of leveraging super that way There's one more aspect I'd like to get your opinion about. I want to draw some rectangles on top of the video frames with `cv2.rectangle(self.frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)`. Would you make a new decorator class that "decorates" the ColorVideo frames with rectangles or would you simply create a RectangledVidoe class that inherits from ColorVideo, or other?

Comment: Are the rectangles always on every frame?

Comment: Yes, they are. In other words, there's a rectangle annotation on the entire video.

Comment: Alright, I can simply make an AnnotatedVideo class inheriting from ColorVideo and then modify the process method to return the annotated frame. That wouldn't work if the rectangle would be there all the time though. If you have any suggestions for the later (rectangle not all the time in the video) I'm all ears.

Comment: Simply add it as a boolean argument on the constructor, saved to an attribute of the class. If true, make the rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

## user input

What happens if the user does not type in `c` or `g`?

## typing

As a general remark, I would include type annotations, so users of your code, (this includes you in 6 months time) can know what to expect.

## docstring

The same goes for a docstring.

You kind of do that already

```
def get_raw_frame(self):
    # Get a bolean and current frame (numpy array) from the webcam
```

But if you turn that into a docstring

```
def get_raw_frame(self):
    """Get a bolean and current frame (numpy array) from the webcam"""
```

IDE's etc can keep track of this.

## inheritance

I would not use inheritance here, but composition. An excellent explanation is given by Brandon Rhodes [here](https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/composition-over-inheritance/)

You can define a procotol.

```
class VideoProcessor(typing.Protocol):
    def process(self, raw_frame:np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        ...
```

And then give 2 implementations:

```
class ColorProcessor(VideoProcessor):
    def process(self, raw_frame: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Return the frame untouched."""
        return raw_frame


class GrayProcessor(VideoProcessor):
    def process(self, raw_frame: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Convert the raw frame to grayscale."""
        return cv2.cvtColor(raw_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Then the init and `process` become something like this:

```
def __init__(
        self, source: int, processor: VideoProcessor
    ):
        self.processor = processor
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(source) 
        # If source = 0 the webcam starts

def process(self):
    """Let the processor process the raw frame."""
    raw_frame = self.get_raw_frame()
    if raw_frame is not None:
        return self.processor.process(raw_frame)
```

This way, If you ever want to implement a sepia, or green version, it's just a matter of implementing another `Processor`.

These processors can also be tested individually, without having to set up a videosource

## Hoist the IO

Another thing I would change, is instead of letting the `Video` class instantiate the connection to the webcam, I would let this be done on a higher level, and have the Video class accept a video source.

Here are [1](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#clean-architecture-python) [2](https://rhodesmill.org/brandon/talks/#hoist) talks on why you would want to do this. This concept is not limited to python ([3](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/))

```
class VideoSource(typing.Protocol):
    def read(self) -> typing.Tuple[bool, np.ndarray]:
        """Read the current frame.

        Returns a boolean success flag, 
        and the current frame, if successful.
        """
        ...

    def release(self) -> None:
        """Release the connection to the video source."""
        ...

def __init__(
    self, source: VideoSource, processor: VideoProcessor
):
    self.processor = processor
    self.capture = source
```

This change makes it even easier to test the `Video` class.

## context manager

Turning `Video` into a `context manager` is very simple:

```
def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.end()
```

## Putting it together

```
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    while True:
        user_preference = input('Enter "c" for color, or "g" for grayscale: ')
        if user_preference in  "cg":
            break

    if user_preference == 'c':
        processor = ColorProcessor()
    if user_preference == 'g':
        processor = GrayProcessor()
    source = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

    with Video(source=source, processor=processor) as video:
        while True:
            video.show_current_frame()

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

## rectangles on the screen

You could even generalize this to have consequent processors, for example if you want to add the rectangles

The Processor itself can be quite simple (I use `dataclasses` to avoid the boiler plate `__init__`:

import dataclasses

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class RectangleProcessor(VideoProcessor):
    x1: int
    y1: int
    x2: int
    y2: int

    color: typing.Tuple[int, int, int]

    def process(self, raw_frame: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return cv2.rectangle(
            raw_frame, (self.x1, self.y1), (self.x2, self.y2), self.color, 2
        )
```

You can implement a chain of processors very simply:

```
class Video:
    def __init__(
        self,
        source: VideoSource,
        processors: typing.Optional[typing.Sequence[VideoProcessor]] = None,
    ):
        self.processors = processors
        self.capture = source

    def process(self) -> np.ndarray:
        raw_frame = self.get_raw_frame()
        if self.processors is None:
            return raw_frame
        for processor in self.processors:
            raw_frame = processor.process(raw_frame)
        return raw_frame
```

This way you can even skip the noop `ColorProcessor`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        user_preference = input('Enter "c" for color, or "g" for grayscale: ')
        if user_preference in "cg":
            break
        while True:


    processors = []
    if user_preference == "g":
        processors.append(GrayProcessor())

    user_preference = input('Do you want to add a rectange [y/N]:')

    if user_preference.lower() == "y":
        processors.append(RectangleProcessor(0, 0, 10, 10, (255, 0, 0)))

    source = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    with Video(source=source, processors=processors) as video:
        while True:
            video.show_current_frame()

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
```

Like this, you can easily add Processors that add timestamps to video's, names to streams, ...

Comment: I'd suggest you add a `main()` function instead of throwing everything in bulk right under the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard.